# Is there a way to include the request port number in NGINX access.log?

Tags: nginx, port, nginx-reverse-proxy

Can I show the port # in the access/error logs with NGINX ? I can run nginx-debug if that helps.

Debian 11, free NGINX 1.22 downloaded release (not built from source)

Comment: Please define "request port number".

Comment: When a request comes to the machine, it comes on a protocol and port number. e.g. a GET request comes on port 80 or 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nginx variables documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_port) on variables shows that `$server_port` variable contains the server side port for the request.

[nginx log module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) documents `log_format` and `access_log` directives.

The default log format is:

```
log_format combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

One can add the port to the end for example for another log format:

```
log_format combinedwithport '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"' $server_port;
```

To actually use this format for logs, one needs to define:

```
access_log /path/to/log/file combinedwithport;
```

It is recommended to add the port to the end of log line so that possible combined log format parsers can still process the log.

Comment: Thank you Tero, very complete and easy to follow. I wound up using both $server_port and $remote_port in the log.